# XML override component Java

Tags: java, xml, overriding

I am having a component that I need to override, the problem is I don't know-how.

### My XML looks like this:

```
<border-layout>

<component name="myFirstComponent"> 
<fix-layout> 
<component name="myController"> 
some options...
</component>

 <component name="needToOverride">
        <fix-position x="222" y="222" width="111" height="10" opaque="false" visible="true"/>
      </component>
</fix-layout>

</border-layout>
```

I could escape some closing tags at the end, but don't take it insight. How can I override "needTOOverride" to modify my positions? the current XML is read-only, and I can't modify it.

I tried some google solutions but did not manage to make this work. Sorry for the dumb question, if it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some XML Serialization and Deserialization Library like [jackson](http:///https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization) or [simplexml](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) for that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).